# Translation of 'I do not need what I think I need'

Tags: translation

Google Translate gives 我不需要我认为我需要的东西 as a translation of 'I do not need what I think I need'.

Is that accurate?

Is 的东西 necessary or is 我不需要我认为我需要 sufficient to convey the meaning?

Comment: It should be 我不需要我认为我需要**的**. But in Chinese, it is more natural to say 我认为我所需要的其实并非我想要的。

Comment: @dan 想要 is want.need should be 需要

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,

> 我不需要我认为我需要的东西

Is okay.

Next:

> Is 的东西 necessary or is 我不需要我认为我需要 sufficient to convey the meaning?

If anything `东西` is unnecessary. `的` on the other hand is essential.

`的` has the function to turn verbs into nouns.

需要 means “to need,” 的 turns `to need` (需要) into 需要的 and means into something more like - `what (I) need` -or- `the things (I) need`.

So `我不需要我认为我需要的东西` could be better phrased as `我不需要我认为我需要的`.

It might be more natural to put it in a flipped order though (i.e.: what I think I need - I don’t (actually) need).